# 2 different styled <ul><li> on one page?

Tags: html, css

I have one page that I'm making and I am stuck. The responsive navbar uses the `<ul><li>` and I want a different style below on the page. I didn't think much about it at first until I got this:

[image]

What can I change to make the general list items in the page, not the menu, to look difgerent?
here is the [page live](http://isellrye.com/links.html)

here is my code

```css
/* General List */
ul.b {
list-style-type: disc;
}

/* Responsive Menu */
#menuBackground {
    background:#5EA5B9;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
 }
#menuContainer {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 1;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font-family:Georgia;
    color:#fff;
    background:#5EA5B9;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
color: #036;     
     background:#fff
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width:auto;
    min-width:100px;
    padding:0 20px
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family:Georgia;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background:#5EA5B9;
    text-align:center;
    padding:16px 0;
    display:none;
    width:100%!important
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto
}

/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px) {
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position:static;
        display:none;
      
      
        white-space: initial;
    }
    
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li,li a {
        width:100%
    }
    
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="b">
<li> <a href="http://www.atlanticwhalewatch.com/" target="_blank">Whalewatching/Fishing</a></li>
<li> <a href="http://www.islesofshoals.com/" target="_blank">Portsmouth Cruises</a></li>
<li> <a href="http://www.nhstateparks.com/odiorne.html" target="_blank">Odiorne Point State Park</a></li>
<li> <a href="http://www.watercountry.com/" target="_blank">Water Country</a></li>
<li> <a href="http://www.portsmouthchamber.org/" target="_blank">Portsmouth Chamber of Commerce</a></li>
<li> <a href="http://www.casinoballroom.com/" target="_blank">Hampton Beach Casino Ballroom</a></li>
<li> <a href="http://www.childrens-museum.org/cmnh/" target="_blank">The Childrens Museum of New Hampshire</a></li>
<li> <a href="http://www.thekitteryoutlets.com/" target="_blank">The Kittery Outlets</a></li>
</ul>

<p>This is the HTML for the menu</p>

<div id="menuBackground">
    <div id="menuContainer">
        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button" />
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="accommodations.html">Accommodations</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="amenities.html">Amenities</a>
            </li>
             <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a>
            </li>
             <li><a href="links.html">Links</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the navbar to keep it's style, but the rest of the list elements on the page not to have the same style as the navbar?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want the navbar to remain the same, but want all other list items to have the regular solid disct circle.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Scope to your Css Class to prevent it from being applied to other page elements that are out of the menu scope.

```
#menuContainer li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font-family:Georgia;
    color:#fff;
    background:#5EA5B9;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#menuContainer li:hover a {
color: #036;     
     background:#fff
}
```

Comment: OP is not looking for a responsive menu solution

Comment: I misunderstood initially. Updated my answer

Comment: thanks anyway but that didn't work. I will try the above answer next

Answer (score 0):

You have styled `li a { with background etc.}` as global which is causing this. to seperate both the thing

You can use  For The Navbar. like this :

```
<nav> 
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</nav>
```

And Css like :

```
nav
{
//some properties
}

nav li
{
   //properties
}
nav li > ul li
{
   //properties
}
```

tag. And keep `li a {}` style as it is for unordered list. Then you will have different effect for Navigation and different for the unordered list. And also it is a good to use  tag for navigation.

The Nav tag added as a prefix in css will make sure that when you have a nav tag wrapped you are dealing with nav and not any unordered list or ordered list.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the menu and update the stylesheet as below.

The style will only then apply to the elements which have that class.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu" class="navmenu">
   <li class="navlist"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li class="navlist"><a href="accommodations.html">Accommodations</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.navmenu {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
.navlist {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
.navlist a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font-family:Georgia;
    color:#fff;
    background:#5EA5B9;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
.navlist:hover a {
color: #036;     
     background:#fff
}
```

Comment: @mlegg When you say it _"didn't work"_, could you explain please? Is the css not applied?

Comment: Your css file shows you haven't removed your previous code - remove the style for `ul`, `li`, `li a`, `li:hover a` and `li ul li a` on http://isellrye.com/styles.css :)

Comment: do you mean this part?  'ul.b {
list-style-type: disc;
}'

Comment: or this part in the menu part?   '/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font-family:Georgia;
    color:#fff;
    background:#5EA5B9;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 1rem;
}


'

Comment: @mlegg You should remove all the CSS you posted in your question

Comment: why? what would the reason be to do that?

Comment: @mlegg The CSS you posted in your question applies the style to all `ul` and `li` elements on your site. The CSS in my answer only applies the style to `ul` and `li` elements with a certain class.